# Error while generating APK, Error "Program type already present: android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator$1"

Tags: android, gradle

**Error Log**

***Program type already present: android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}***

> This error comes after migrated gradle from 1.5.0 to 3.1.0 and compile
>   sdk version 23 to 26. The app build and run on device in debug mode
>   correctly, but when i am try to build apk or generate Signed apk,
>   above error comes. I am using android 3.1.1.

**Gradle**
**app level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    } }

'./utils/global.gradle'
```

**Module level mobile gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}


android {

    // Always target latest version
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions '18032613'

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    signingConfigs {
        example {
            keyAlias 'example'
            keyPassword 'test'
            storeFile file('../signing/keystore')
            storePassword 'test'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId 'com.example.com'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        //versionCode getDate().toInteger()
        versionCode 18032613
        versionName "1.4.28"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.example
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

        }

        debug {

            debuggable false
            //versionNameSuffix ".${getDate()}-debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".${18032613}-debug"
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            resValue "integer", '__leak_canary_max_stored_leaks', '50'

        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
        //incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "12g"
    }
    //To solve error "Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target."
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {

    // JARs from lib directory
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    // Project Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20"
    compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    //debugCompile project(path: ':utilsLibrary', configuration: "${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}Debug")
    //releaseCompile project(path: ':utilsLibrary', configuration: "${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}Release")

    implementation project(':utilsLibrary')

    wearApp project(':keycutWearable')

    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'
    implementation 'javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'

    //compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.3.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**Module level wearable gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    // Always target latest version
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions '18032613'

    signingConfigs {
        example {
            keyAlias 'example'
            keyPassword 'test'
            storeFile file('../signing/keystore')
            storePassword 'test'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.com"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        //versionCode getDate().toInteger()
        versionCode 18032613
        versionName "1.2"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keycut

    }


    buildTypes {

        release {

            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

        }

        debug {

            debuggable false
            //versionNameSuffix ".${getDate()}-debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".${18032613}-debug"
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

dependencies {

    // Project Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20"
    compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    // Wearable Service
    implementation ('com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0.0'
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    // Utils Library
    //debugCompile project(path: ':utilsLibrary', configuration: "${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}Debug")
    //releaseCompile project(path: ':utilsLibrary', configuration: "${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}Release")

    implementation project(':utilsLibrary')

}
```

**Module level gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {

    // Always target latest version
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions '18032613'

    defaultPublishConfig 'release'
    publishNonDefault true

    // Generate version code from date
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        //versionCode getDate().toInteger()
        versionCode 18032613
        //buildConfigField 'String', 'ADMOB_BANNER_ID', '"BANNERID"'
        //buildConfigField 'String', 'ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ID', '"INTERSTITIALID"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'ADMOB_BANNER_ID', '"ca-app-pub-55663938299199712/4792255984"'      //orginal
        buildConfigField 'String', 'ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ID', '"ca-app-pub-55663938299199712/6596667788"'    //orginal

        //buildConfigField 'String', 'ADMOB_BANNER_ID', '""'
        //buildConfigField 'String', 'ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ID', '""'

        //buildConfigField 'String', 'SUPPORT_URL', '"http://example.support.url"'
        //buildConfigField 'String', 'COMPANY_NAME', '"Your Company Name"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SUPPORT_URL', '"http://www.company.in/"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'COMPANY_NAME', '"Company"'

        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

        }

        debug {

            debuggable false

            //versionNameSuffix ".${getDate()}-debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".${18032613}-debug"
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

        }

    }

    productFlavors {

        'com.example.com' {

            manifestPlaceholders = [ appPackageName: 'com.example.com' ]
            buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_PACKAGE_NAME', '"com.example.com"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_DISPLAY_NAME', '"example"'


        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

dependencies {

    // Project Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20"
    compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'

    // Find bugs
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'

    // Javax Annotations
    implementation 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    api 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'


    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'


}
```

can anybody help me to solve the error!

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: I have just resolved similar kind of issue. This is caused because some of the dependencies are imported twice or more due to transitive dependency. To resolve issue attempt making individual module to detect which module is throwing this error. Then find all the dependencies using gradle dependency. Exclude dependency which is alreay included by other lib.

Comment: I use 'multidex' in all module. Now get 'Cause: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.class' error at apk generation time. I use recycler view in the main module only. I don't understand why this error occurs.

Comment: run grade dependencies on all module and post result