# How to exclude java file from external library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator$1;

I want to exclude `android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator` from `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0` and `com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0`.

Is it possible or is any other way to solve the above problem?

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 19

Comment: Check this response: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780470/4845438

Comment: I am added multidex, now Cause: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.class comes

Comment: show me your build.gradle file please, i need more information about your problem.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003726/error-while-generating-apk-error-program-type-already-present-android-support  all gradle file present.